# Fit long table in one PDF page

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a really long chart created using tables and when I export it to PDF I cannot fit it inside one page so I'd to shrink it to fit onto one as well as fit it over several pages (but first option is the real important one here).

To export it as PDF I'm not doing any custom function, just printing the page and save it as PDF.

How could I do this? I wouldn't mind to refactor the whole chart using something else.

Comment: can you use tr{ page-break-before: always;}

Comment: Do you want to fit it over several pages, or shrink it to fit onto one?

Comment: Not enough info. How are you exporting it to PDF?

Comment: Update question. 
page-break-before: always doesn't apply any changes